# SQL comparison report on cartesian product using subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, cross-join

I'm a student building a comparison report query in MySQL on a database that tracks customers, products, and purchases in separate tables. I have to create a report that shows how many products were sold every month for each province using a subquery. I was told to use a cross join between product and customer, however, my query runs into a problem when I try to group them as the records all collapse into each other and I don't understand why this is happening. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to approach this problem since my customer and product table don't have any values that intersect with each other except through the purchase table.

These are my create table scripts

```
CREATE TABLE 'customer' (
'CustomerID' INT NOT NULL,
'City' VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
'Province' CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ('CustomerID'));

CREATE TABLE 'product' (
'ProductID' INT NOT NULL,
'ProductName' VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
'Price' DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ('ProductID')); 

CREATE TABLE 'purchase' (
'PurchaseID' INT NOT NULL,
'PurchaseDate' DATE NOT NULL,
'customer_CustomerID' INT NOT NULL,
'product_ProductID' INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY ('PurchaseID'),
CONSTRAINT 'fk_purchase_customer'
 FOREIGN KEY ('customer_CustomerID')
 REFERENCES 'customer' ('CustomerID'),
CONSTRAINT 'fk_purchase_product'
 FOREIGN KEY ('product_ProductID')
 REFERENCES 'product' ('ProductID'));
```

This is the query that I have written as I have understood the instructions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT province, productName AS Product, JanTotalSales
FROM PRODUCT cross join CUSTOMER
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT purchaseID, product_productID, customer_customerID, COUNT(purchaseDate) AS JanTotalSales
    FROM PURCHASE
    WHERE MONTH(purchaseDate) = 01
    )JAN ON PRODUCT.productID = JAN.product_productID
     GROUP BY province, productID;
```

I should be getting results like this

| Province | Product | JanTotalSales | FebTotalSales | ... | TotalSales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| QC | Paper | 1 | NULL | ... | 1 |
| ON | Paper | 1 | 2 | ... | 3 |
| AB | Paper | 1 | NULL | ... | 1 |
| AB | Wire | 2 | 2 | ... | 4 |
| ON | Wire | 2 | 1 | ... | 3 |
| NULL | Kit | NULL | NULL | ... | NULL |
| SK | Gummy | 1 | 1 | ... | 2 |
| NULL | Bag | NULL | NULL | ... | NULL |

However, I receive results like this when I do it on the January subquery.

| Province | Product | JanTotalSales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | Paper | NULL |
| AB | Wire | NULL |
| AB | Kit | NULL |
| AB | Kit | 13 |
| ON | Paper | NULL |
| ON | Wire | NULL |
| ON | Kit | NULL |
| ON | Kit | 13 |

I appreciate whatever help you can give to show me where I'm going wrong. From what I understand it's something to do with how the grouping occurs but I can't figure out why.

Comment: I doubt that you need the cross join on customer.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. I asked my professor and he said to cross join customer with the product. I tried to left join product to purchase and then left join purchase to the customer to group them, which provided the correct results for January, but then the province column became ambiguous and it messed up the results when I added the other months.

Comment: Based on the change to your question, the query is no longer for just one month and year of sales, in which case you could have used *null* as the gap filler. *Now*, you need this on a "sliding" timeline and you would like to show all entities with/without a purchase at a given time, therefore, you will need to fill the gaps with some mechanism. My above comment was based on the original query that could be solved without a CROSS JOIN. Also, you seemed to have added a date/year PIVOT requirement to your original question and by doing so the query above will need to do more work.

Comment: Yes, I realize that the original question didn't encompass the scope of what I was attempting to do. It's supposed to include sales for each month and the total for the year, I was only using January because the rest of the code was similar. I don't understand the PIVOT requirement, as we have not reached that topic in the course so far.

Comment: The data sets are returned in rows with by a date dimension or value (purchase.PurchaseDate). Pivoting the data is basically pushing the values that lay vertically out horizontally by distinct values within a grouping. In the problem above, the distinct concatenation of year and month would be pushed out and an aggregate of COUNT(purchaseDate) would align and fill in appropriately and the whole structure would collapse.